# NSString to std::string replacing symbols used in encryption

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, objective-c++, stdstring

Basically I am receiving some funky encryption characters in std::string form and storing them in the keychain as an NSString (since it has to be an NSObject of sorts I believe). A simple `[text UTF8String]` works and the result is equal to initial std::string. Brilliant.

When taking out the NSString and getting it back to std::string I find a number of the more obscure symbols are being substituted for others or other characters are being added entirely. `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is the only encoding I have tried that gives me close to the initial text.

Are there any other ways to convert a std::string to NSString, allowing me to preserve these symbols?

example NSString:
`õÑ[v¶±4%üÂ
Á˛‰€º§c(Â{Q®∑¸<Ò˚Êıé7≤º%ï`

becomes std::string:
`√µ√ë[v¬∂¬±4%√º√Ç
√ÅÀõ‚Ä∞‚Ç¨¬∫¬ßc(√Ç{Q¬Æ‚àë¬∏<√íÀö√äƒ±√©7‚â§¬∫%√Ø`

Using `std::string encryptedText = [nSStringText cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

ASCII encoding crashes, losslessascii gives me odd char symbols..

Comment: Note this result is particularly bad, some hits only a couple of chars are different, but you can see many of the chars are being changed for about 4 others.

Comment: Why not store them as raw bits (NSData)?

You can get the raw data from std::string using `data()` member function and use that to initialize your NSData object. This way you should not need to worry about encoding. Then when you need it, you simply recreate your std::string from the raw data in NSData.